# How do I do this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{(3x^2−27)(8x^2)6}{4(9−3x)(x^2+3)} =
\frac{\tan(x+4)}{\log(x+1/4)}$$
I've simplified the left side of the equation but I do not know how to go further than that.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $3x^2-27 = 3(x-3)(x+3)$ and $9-3x=-3(x-3)$ so there is more you can do on the left side. Still, the rest looks gnarly.

Comment: Maybe you can give us an "unsimplified" left side? I feel like you might have made an error there....

Answer (score 1):

Let us have a look to the function $$f(x)=\frac{(3x^2−27)(8x^2)6}{4(9−3x)(x^2+3)} -\frac{\tan(x+4)}{\log(x+1/4)}$$ which, assuming that $x\neq 3$, can simplify to $$f(x)=-\frac{12 x^2 (x+3)}{x^2+3}-\frac{\tan(x+4)}{\log(x+1/4)}$$ Because of the logarithm, the function is undefined if $x \leq -\frac{1}{4}$ and it has a series of vertical asymptotes corresponding to $x=\frac{3}{4}$ because of the logarithm in the denominator and at $x=\pi  \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)-4$ because of the tangent. You should notice that two asymptotes are very close to each other ($(x=\frac{3}{4}=0.75$ and $x=\frac{3 \pi }{2}-4 \simeq 0.712389$).

So, now, where are the roots ? By inspection, you can notice that $f(-\frac{1}{4})=-\frac{33}{49}$ and that $f(0)=\frac{\tan (4)}{\log (4)} \gt 0$. So, you have one root in this interval. If you use Newton iterative scheme, you will locate this first root at $-0.170284$. The next root will be after the second vertical asymptote ($1.02698$), the next one before the third vertical asymptote ($3.86429$), the next one at $7.00004$ and so on for ever because of the behavior of the tangent.